# Convertir array de bytes en una imagen

Tags: java, netbeans

Tengo un array de bytes que me viene como resultado de hacer un get a un metodo "x". Ahora mi duda, es como convertir este array de bytes, en una imagen para asi setearle la imagen a un JLabel especifico.

```
         ImageIcon image;
         ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(t.getFoto());
         BufferedImage imagen;
        try {
            imagen = ImageIO.read(bis);
            portada.setIcon((Icon) imagen);
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(VeryModificarTrailers.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
```

> Obtengo el array de bytes a traves de un get, luego intento convertir el byteArray a una imagen, para despues setearsela a la portada que seria mi jlabel.

Answer (score 1):

```
ImageIcon image;
ByteArrayInputStream bis = new ByteArrayInputStream(t.getFoto());
BufferedImage Imagen = ImageIO.read(bis);
portada.setIcon(Imagen);
```

Comment: Hola antoni, me pide NetBeans que ponga un try catch para ejecutar lo que me pusiste, ademas me pide castear `portada.setIcon(Imagen);`  la Imagen a  icon. Te edito la publicacion original para que lo puedas ver